# How to check if a number is out of sequence?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Working on an SQL Server project, one of the requirements as part of a data import is to validate that all the tags are in the correct order and I'm not really worried about missing tages. What I'm looking for should return '7010' as being out of sequence based on the order the data was imported (the key). I know how to do this externally using other languages but the size of the imports makes this a slow process and would like to find a native SQL method.

```
    key tag
    1   7001
    2   7002
    3   7004
    4   7010
    5   7005
    6   7006
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Would you be able to show the code you've attempted for command?

Comment: SQL Server 2015

Comment: @StephenCase 1) There is no such thing as SQL Server 2015. 2) Please post the query you have tried to solve this. 3) Please show one or more examples of the expected output for different scenarios.

Comment: Can you post an example of the secondary table holding the sequence pattern, as well as an example of your expected output, please?

Comment: I will post an example over the weekend, need some time to thoroughly think it through.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or newer then you can use `LEAD()` or `LAG()` to look at the key value of the next/previous row.

```
SELECT [key]
    , tag
FROM
(SELECT
    [key],
    tag,
    LEAD(tag) OVER (ORDER BY [key]) next_tag,
    LAG(tag) OVER (ORDER BY [key]) prev_tag
FROM myTable ) r
WHERE (tag + 1 <> next_tag AND tag - 1 <> prev_tag)
```

Also, I believe from your example both 7004 and 7010 are out of sequence (if the sequence is starting at key=1 and incrementing by 1).

If you are using SQL Server 2008R2 / 2005 etc. then you can use a double self-join to get the same result.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM myTable t
    LEFT JOIN myTable tprev on t.[key] = tprev.[key] + 1
    LEFT JOIN myTable tnext on t.[key] = tnext.[key] - 1
WHERE tprev.tag + 1 <> t.tag
    AND tnext.tag - 1 <> t.tag
```

Comment: Need to order by key as well

Comment: @ajeh I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. I have it ordered by key.

Comment: Thank you. Missing tags are ok as long as the ones that are present are in the correct order.

Comment: Any thought on how this could be done if the value was text and the sequence pattern was kept in another table?

Answer (score 0):

Is this your requirment?

```
    DECLARE @tb TABLE([KEY] int,tag INT )
    INSERT INTO @tb ( [KEY], tag )
    VALUES  (1,7001),(2,7002),(3,7004),(4,7010),(5,7005),(6,7006)
    SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT *,LEAD(tag)OVER(ORDER BY [key]) AS n FROM @tb
    ) AS t
    WHERE t.tag>t.n
```

```
KEY         tag         n
----------- ----------- -----------
4           7010        7005
```